# No opacity IF element is visible

Tags: jquery, css, opacity

How do I get this effect that if the error message is displayed the form should not lose its opacity, but if the error message is hidden, opacity should be applied only when the form is hovered on?

HTML:

```
<section>
    <form id="form" name="form" action="login.php" method="post">  

    <ul>
        <li>
        <span class="er" style="display:none;">&nbsp;</span>
        </li> <br />

        <li>
        <label for="name">Name</label>  
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />       
        </li>

        <li> 
        <label for="pass">Password</label>  
        <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" />  
        </li>

    </ul>
        <input type="submit" value="Log In" />  

</form>  
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section { 
     opacity: 0.5;
     transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
     -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;  
}

section:hover{
    opacity: 100;
     transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
     -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: all 1 ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#form').bind('submit', function (e) {
            var self = $(this);

            jQuery.post(self.attr('action'), self.serialize(), function (response) {
                if ($("#name").val() == "" || $("#pass").val() == "") {
                    $("span.er").text('Field cannot be blank!');
                                    $("span.er").show();    
                }
                else if (response.success) {
                    window.location.href='home.php';
                } else {
            $("span.er").text('Invalid username or password! Please try again.');
                    $("span.er").show();
                }
            }, 'json');

            e.preventDefault(); //prevent the form being posted 
        });
```

I tried adding this line to above jQuery function wherever the `span.er` is set to `show()`:

```
$("section").css('opacity', '100');
```

^This setting should be applied only when `span.er` is visible. However the problem with this is that once the error message is displayed, the opacity setting is applied regardless of whether `span.er` is visible or hidden.

Comment: Change ``100`` for ``1`` in ``opacity``.

Comment: @fuz3d http://jsfiddle.net/c6UbY/6/ also please change opacity 1 to less than 1

Comment: perhaps you want this http://jsfiddle.net/c6UbY/7/

Comment: @marcosfromero, no it didn't solve the problem. @experimentX no that's not what I want. What I want in other words is check if span.er is visible, and if it is, set the opacity of the form to 1. Else if there is no error message, the opacity of the form should be 1 only when the user hovers on the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of manipulating the visibility of the span, if an error message is to come up you could add the `er` class to the parent `section` element itself

from there you can control the visibility of the actual `li` that contains your message e.g.

```
section li:first-child {display: none;}
section.er li:first-child {display: block;}
```

and also the hover transitions at the same time:

```
section { 
     display: block;
     opacity: 0.5;
     transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
     -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;  
}

section.er, section:hover {
    opacity: 100;
     transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
     -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: all 1 ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

all the jQuery would need to do is add or remove the class name from the section dependant on if the form does/doesn't pass validation

Comment: :first-child{} isn't a cross browser solution but good answer :)

Comment: @Val, thanks :) .. I could have, of course, added a class of "first" to that first list-item, to make it more backwards compatible - I was kind of presuming that as the code is HTML5 (sections) that there are various scripty goodness IE workarounds already in place - I was just trying to show that it was the li that needs toggled rather than an inner span, which might still show the space or bullet ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').mouseover(function (){
  $('span.er').css('opacty':1);
  if(!$("span.er:visible")){
     $('form').css({'opacity',0.5});
  }
});
```

And you are very difficult to understand you have confused the hell out of us, put it on bullet points the actions and their priority if you find it that difficult

as for the code above when user mouses over the `<form>` tag it will change opacity to one unless its visible which will be 0.5 or 50%